# NodeJs MSSQL combining results of multiple queries

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Working with Express, node, the MSSQL package to create a backend for an application, and I would like to do as much processing on the server as possible before sending to the client.

I have two queries I need to run, but I need to combine the data in a specific way before sending to the client.

The first query gathers data that will be of a one-to-one relationship, and the other is a one-to-many relationship. I would like to append the one-to-Many onto the One-to-one.

First Query:

```
select updatedInfo.*,
            nameInfo.*, nameInfo.updated as nameUpdated, nameInfo.alreadyCorrect as nameWasCorrect,
            addressInfo.*, addressInfo.alreadyCorrect as addWasCorrect, addressInfo.updated as addUpdated,
            phoneInfo.*, phoneInfo.alreadyCorrect as phoneWasCorrect, phoneInfo.updated as phoneUpdated,
            emailInfo.*, emailInfo.alreadyCorrect as emailWasCorrect, emailInfo.updated as emailUpdated
            from updatedInfo join nameInfo on updatedInfo.IndivId=nameInfo.nameInfoId
                  join addressInfo on updatedInfo.IndivId=addressInfo.addressInfoId
                  join emailInfo on updatedInfo.IndivId=emailInfo.emailInfoId
                  join phoneInfo on updatedInfo.IndivId=phoneInfo.phoneInfoId
                  where updatedInfo.correctedInFNV is not null
                  order by updatedInfo.IndivId
```

Second Query: *ID is a variable passed to the query*

```
select * from positionInfo where IndivId='${id}'
```

How would I go about appending the second query results to the first on the correct record?

I'm using the mssql package and using it like this:

```
var sqlConfig = {
    server: 'IP',
    database: 'db',
    user: 'sweeper',
    password: 'pass'
}
const connPool = new mssql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig, err => {
    console.error(err);
});

var query = {
     getAllUpdatedPool: () => {
         connPool.Request().query(`----first query ----`)
                 .then((set) => {
                      console.log(set);
                      return set;
                 }).catch((err) => {
                      console.error(err);
                      return err;
                 });
     },
     getPositionByIdPool: (id) => {
          connPool.Request().query(`----second query-----`)
                  .then((set) => {
                       console.log(set);
                       return set;
                  }).catch((err) => {
                       console.error(err);
                       return err;
                  });
```

How should I call these to add the results of the second query to the results of the first one as an additional property? Callbacks are making this confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like both queries execute on the same server, have you considered using subqueries? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017). If you can express what you're trying to do in SQL it'll probably be 1) cleaner and 2) faster to just do it with subqueries than manually merging recordsets. If they exist on different servers, you could use linked servers to achieve the same subquery result.